# Integrate React Js with Drupal-8

Tags: php, drupal-8

Is their a way to integrate Drupal-8 and React js.

I mean frontend be React js and backed be of Drupal-8.

I have gone through:

http://www.anexusit.com/blog/how-to-add-reactjs-drupal-8-composer

I have followed all the steps and done but dont know how can I use it.

Can any one please suggest some clear steps to me ..

also followed:

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/564gdy/react_frontend_for_your_drupal_8_backend/

In need of some clear suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: react is just a library.. just include the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article, but didn't get time to try it as I am a bit busy on another thing. Hope this will help you.

https://medium.com/@Userium/headless-drupal-build-a-drupal-8-api-with-a-reactjs-front-end-e43bf0fb94db#.2qn0u2im4

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building a module for Drupal 8 using ReactJS. I recommend you to see this: https://github.com/blackwood/drupal-react_blocks that's for Drupal 7 and then to Drupal 8 try to understand this portuguese steps: http://www.drupalbrasil.com.br/drupal-8-e-reactjs

Before starting just install libraries module to Drupal 8 and then install rest web services so after that you can copy and paste code from above to start learning how the integration works.

Using drush to install libraries and rest web services module:

```
drush dl libraries
drush en -y libraries
drush dl rest
drush en -y rest
```

I recommend you to use PHP 7 because I'm currently having troubles installing rest module for PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you try this module (found in this repository: https://github.com/dtraft/react_quickstart ). Its built with react and can run in Drupal 8.

Add this folder in *sites/all/modules/* or you can also create a subdirectory for modules you make in *sites/all/modules/custom/* .

And then follow the instructions found below the repository's link or the read.md file.

Clear your site's cache in your site's Admin/Configuration/Performance/ then click *Clear all cache*. Save the configuration.

Then go to, *Extend* menu of your site search for "Decoupled Drupal with React Quickstart". Install it.

Lastly, go to *Structure/Block Layout* menu and add a block any part of you site and then you can choose from all existing blocks. Choose *Clock Face Block*.

Refresh your sites home page and there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate react and use inside, you can simply create a react app anywhere and when you finished just do a

```
npm run build
```

once you finished just copy the js and css file generated inside build/static folder :(js/main.something.js and css/main.something.css) to your drupal module or theme and then just reference theme in module_or_theme.libraries.yml